# Avoid double counting in Power BI sum

Tags: powerbi, dax

I'm trying to count the number of factory operators used to manufacture parts during a shift but I am double counting them as this example illustrates:

**Machine Groups**

- Group A : Machines 1 and 2, employing 3 operators per shift
- Group B : Machines 3 and 4, employing 2 operators per shift

**Shift Output**

| Group | Machine | Operators | Item | Quantity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Grp A | Mach 1 | 3 | Nuts | 1000 |
| Grp A | Mach 2 | 3 | Bolts | 500 |
| Grp B | Mach 3 | 2 | Washers | 2000 |
| Grp B | Mach 4 | 2 | Springs | 1500 |
| **Total** |  | **10** |  | **5000** |

So the total quantity of parts is correct but the total number of operators is incorrect as it should only be 5. Operators are being double-counted because they make 2 different parts.

I have tried using an implicit sum on the operators column and also a DAX sum

- Sum Operators = SUM(Production(Operators))

I have also tried with a matrix rather than a simple table but get the same result.

(There will not always be 2 items per shift. There could sometimes be 3 or 4)

Comment: I don't believe there is sufficient information in your sample table.  For example, how do we know that the same operators work on the two different machines?  What if the Mach 1 used three operators, and Mach 2 used only two operators?  etc, etc

Comment: For any shift, the same operators remain working in the same group but on any machine within that group. On the next shift there will be a different set of operators assigned to the groups.

Comment: Group A always has 3 operators per shift and they may work on any combination of the machines throughout the shift. I want to show; the quantity of each type of part produced by each group; the number of operators working in each group; and the total number of parts & operators.(SImilarly with Grp B). There may be times when they are both making the same item on different machines and times when they are making different items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you can

- click the down arrow on the Operators Values line.
- Select to create a new quick measure
- Average (or Min or Max since they would all be the same) by Group

Then you can delete the original Operators entry and rename this new one.

[image]

*Note: I am very new with this so there may be more efficient methods to do this*

Comment: Thanks, that works. Now I just need to look up those functions to understand why!

Comment: @Yonah The one I used is what Power BI generates when I went through the User Interface to create the aggregation by group.

Comment: I've only made measures by selecting new Measure and then typing in a formula. I have not come across a way of getting Power BI to generate measures for me.

Comment: @Yonah Try following the steps I outlined in my answer.

Comment: Neat! That's a really useful option.

Comment: Just used quick measure again to build another formula and it's a real time saver, so thanks for showing me this.

Answer (score 0):

I've had a read and play and come up with an alternative which also works:

[image: DAX]